# Add Name Tag to EBS snapshot created by boto.create_image()

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

How can I add a Name tag to an EBS snapshot created automatically by boto's create_image() function?

I have an EBS backed instance with another EBS volume attached. What I do is I create a block_device_mapping and use:

```
ec2_con.create_image(instance_id, name, description, no_reboot, block_device_mapping)
```

This creates a new AMI and two snapshots, one of the root EBS and another of the attached one.

**What I want is to tag these snapshots.**

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the snapshot(s) you can simply run the add_tag method on it:

mySnapshot.add_tag("Name","myName")

"Name" is just another tag that happens to appear in the console prominently.